# what does krutchina mean?

Tags: перевод

I'm reading one of the russian folktales but I don't know what Krutchina means. It's written "Krutchina (sorrow)". Is it a surname with a meaning 'sorrow'?

Comment: Never heard a tale with a hero named "Кручина". But yes, this word means "sorrow".

Comment: If it's a surname (I haven't heard that surname), the stress would most likely be in a different place (Kr`u chi na) than the the noun (kru ch`i na).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кручина не имя и не фамилия. Кручина - это имя существительное, используемое в русском фольклоре, со значением "грусть, тоска, печаль".

"Кручина" is not a name and not a surname. "Кручина" is a noun that is used in Russian folklore, meaning "sorrow".

http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: The question was in English. Most prbably the OP does not speak any bit of Russian so please answer in English.

Comment: I use Google translator, thank you so much Матвей Дёмин.

Comment: @user9995 The answer is quite correct but in tales you may also find the word "кручиниться", it means - "грустить" (the verb from the same word). From Pushkin: "Не кручинься, Бог с тобой" - it means, не грусти.

Answer (score 5):

Кручина may well be a surname (e.g., [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,*%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80*%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0,_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)), albeit in a folktale it most likely means "sorrow".

A bit of context could help...